# Users Directory Deleter

Tags: python, directory

So I'm trying to code a directory deleter without specifying the Users so I can pass the program to my friends too without having to make multiple version for each of them is there any way I can do this?

And I'm also getting access denied so is there any way I can ask the user or the pc permission or something like that?

This is the code so far:

```
import shutil

shutil.rmtree('directory')

print("Directories deleted")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, I am a bit confused here, you want to take input for directory path from the user or not?

Comment: And to delete a directory, you can use `OS module`, [here's one example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-directory-or-file-using-python/)